# using c++ how do I get the rgb values of a window open on my desktop?

Tags: c++

I have a mouse event that will move to a particular part of the screen (x,y cordinates) but I need to be able to check the pixel color of that particular x and y.  I just want to be able to notice when that particular part of my screen changes which in this case the pop up is always in the same spot and the same color.  Any one have any ideas, is this the wrong way to go about this? Thanks, if this is a poor explanation let me know.

Comment: C++ doesn't have the concept of a window, a mouse pointer, or a screen. So you're obviously using some library and/or framework on some platform Which library/framework on which platform?

Comment: The important context here is not the language you are using, but the graphics APIs against which you are programming.

Comment: Answer depends very strongly on the operating system running.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of windows, it is

```
POINT      pt;
COLORREF   cr;
HDC        hdcScreen;

hdcScreen = CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"), NULL, NULL, NULL);
cr = GetPixel(hdcScreen, pt.x, pt.y);
DeleteDC(hdcScreen);
```

Comment: That gets just one pixel,  i think he wants the full window

Comment: He mentioned that _'I need to be able to check the pixel color of that particular x and y'_ so I assume he want just one pixel. However, to get the full window, one should call BitBlt on the HDC of the window.

Comment: nariul you are a life saver! thank you that is exactly what I needed and thanks everyone else.

Comment: So I am using dev c++ and I have VS express but it has been weird navigating so far so maybe I need to use that? I copied Naruil's code verbatim other than adding #include <windows.h> #include <iostream>
using namespace std; I am getting errors like undefined reference to`_imp__CreateDCA@16' as well as the same error for GetPixel & DeleteDC do I need additional library or something? & [Error] ld returned 1 exit status.  I am probably way out of my league I just started C++ so sorry for so many questions and problems.

Comment: I could always come back to this project when I am a little more competent as I know I am trying to run before I walk.

Comment: It's because your linker cannot find the definations of those functions. You should link your program with proper libraries. In your case, the library is `gdi32.a`.